# Why does Messages keep crashing on my Mac whenever I try to send a video?

Tags: mac, crash, macos-monterey

I am running macOS Monterey (12.2.1) on a late 2014 Mac mini.

I tried sending this video I screen recorded on my Mac of some trick I discovered; type: .mov; size: 1,257,432 bytes (2.1MB). I dragged it into the messages window, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and it crashed. The video never sent. I tried different video formats. I tried a shorter cut of the video. I tried sending it from my photos library.

I've tried everything. Rebooting, signing out of iMessage, clearing all messaging data.

None of those worked.

What could be causing this and how could I fix it? I can send images and GIFs (I sent a gif of the video. That sent, but it wouldn't play for the recipient.) and regular text messages. I don't feel like AirDropping the video to my iPhone and sending it one there, because this is a problem on my Mac and I want to fix it.

What can I do?

This is where the messages app disappears is where it crashes.

[image: Animation of the issue.]

And here is the output of the console log, starting from when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
2022-02-24 15:19:28.533536 (gui/502 [100003]) <Warning>: failed lookup: name = com.apple.DFRSystemExtra.InputMenu.disableinput, flags = 0x1, requestor = TextInputMenuAg[508], error = 3: No such process
2022-02-24 15:19:29.708974 (system/com.apple.netauth.sys.auth [5266]) <Notice>: service exited: dirty = 0, supported pressured-exit = 0
2022-02-24 15:19:29.708991 (system/com.apple.netauth.sys.auth [5266]) <Notice>: exited due to exit(0)
2022-02-24 15:19:29.708997 (system/com.apple.netauth.sys.auth [5266]) <Notice>: service state: exited
2022-02-24 15:19:29.709002 (system/com.apple.netauth.sys.auth [5266]) <Notice>: internal event: EXITED, code = 0
2022-02-24 15:19:29.709006 (system/com.apple.netauth.sys.auth [5266]) <Notice>: job state = exited
2022-02-24 15:19:29.709011 (system) <Notice>: service inactive: com.apple.netauth.sys.auth
2022-02-24 15:19:29.709029 (system/com.apple.netauth.sys.auth [5266]) <Notice>: service state: not running
2022-02-24 15:19:29.709039 (pid/5266 [NetAuthSysAgent]) <Notice>: shutting down
2022-02-24 15:19:29.709043 (pid/5266 [NetAuthSysAgent]) <Notice>: removing active service: com.apple.filesystems.netfs.PlugInLibraryService
2022-02-24 15:19:29.709071 (pid/5266/com.apple.filesystems.netfs.PlugInLibraryService [5267]) <Notice>: signaled service: Killed: 9
2022-02-24 15:19:29.709076 (pid/5266/com.apple.filesystems.netfs.PlugInLibraryService [5267]) <Notice>: service state: SIGKILLed
2022-02-24 15:19:29.709081 (pid/5266/com.apple.filesystems.netfs.PlugInLibraryService [5267]) <Notice>: scheduling cleanup in 3 sec after sending Killed: 9
2022-02-24 15:19:29.709118 (pid/5266/com.apple.MTLCompilerService) <Notice>: internal event: PETRIFIED, code = 0
2022-02-24 15:19:29.709130 (pid/5266/com.apple.audio.AUHostingService.x86-64) <Notice>: internal event: PETRIFIED, code = 0
2022-02-24 15:19:29.709137 (pid/5266/com.apple.audio.AUHostingService.arm64e) <Notice>: internal event: PETRIFIED, code = 0
2022-02-24 15:19:29.709144 (pid/5266/com.apple.audio.Core-Audio-Driver-Service.helper) <Notice>: internal event: PETRIFIED, code = 0
2022-02-24 15:19:29.709152 (pid/5266/com.apple.audio.Core-Audio-Driver-Service) <Notice>: internal event: PETRIFIED, code = 0
2022-02-24 15:19:29.709734 (pid/5266/com.apple.filesystems.netfs.PlugInLibraryService [5267]) <Notice>: service exited: dirty = 0, supported pressured-exit = 1
2022-02-24 15:19:29.709740 (pid/5266/com.apple.filesystems.netfs.PlugInLibraryService [5267]) <Notice>: exited due to SIGKILL | sent by launchd[1]
2022-02-24 15:19:29.709745 (pid/5266/com.apple.filesystems.netfs.PlugInLibraryService [5267]) <Notice>: service state: exited
2022-02-24 15:19:29.709749 (pid/5266/com.apple.filesystems.netfs.PlugInLibraryService [5267]) <Notice>: internal event: EXITED, code = 0
2022-02-24 15:19:29.709753 (pid/5266 [NetAuthSysAgent]) <Notice>: service inactive: com.apple.filesystems.netfs.PlugInLibraryService
2022-02-24 15:19:29.709770 (pid/5266/com.apple.filesystems.netfs.PlugInLibraryService [5267]) <Notice>: internal event: PETRIFIED, code = 0
2022-02-24 15:19:29.709774 (pid/5266 [NetAuthSysAgent]) <Notice>: cleaning up
2022-02-24 15:19:29.709779 (pid/5266/com.apple.filesystems.netfs.PlugInLibraryService [5267]) <Notice>: service state: not running
2022-02-24 15:19:29.709801 (pid/5267 [PlugInLibrarySe]) <Notice>: shutting down
2022-02-24 15:19:29.709810 (pid/5267 [PlugInLibrarySe]) <Notice>: cleaning up
2022-02-24 15:19:29.709817 (system) <Notice>: removing child: pid/5266
2022-02-24 15:19:29.709829 (system) <Notice>: removing child: pid/5267
2022-02-24 15:19:31.275926 (gui/502 [100003]) <Warning>: failed lookup: name = com.apple.DFRSystemExtra.InputMenu.disableinput, flags = 0x1, requestor = TextInputMenuAg[508], error = 3: No such process
2022-02-24 15:19:32.820784 (gui/502/application.com.apple.MobileSMS.1152921500311915211.1152921500311915220 [5283]) <Notice>: service exited: dirty = 0, supported pressured-exit = 0
2022-02-24 15:19:32.820802 (gui/502/application.com.apple.MobileSMS.1152921500311915211.1152921500311915220 [5283]) <Notice>: Service exited due to SIGILL | sent by exc handler[5283]
2022-02-24 15:19:32.820806 (gui/502/application.com.apple.MobileSMS.1152921500311915211.1152921500311915220 [5283]) <Notice>: exited due to SIGILL | sent by exc handler[5283]
2022-02-24 15:19:32.820811 (gui/502/application.com.apple.MobileSMS.1152921500311915211.1152921500311915220 [5283]) <Notice>: service has crashed 1 times in a row
2022-02-24 15:19:32.820816 (gui/502/application.com.apple.MobileSMS.1152921500311915211.1152921500311915220 [5283]) <Notice>: service state: exited
2022-02-24 15:19:32.820822 (gui/502/application.com.apple.MobileSMS.1152921500311915211.1152921500311915220 [5283]) <Notice>: internal event: EXITED, code = 0
2022-02-24 15:19:32.820860 (gui/502/application.com.apple.MobileSMS.1152921500311915211.1152921500311915220 [5283]) <Notice>: job state = exited
2022-02-24 15:19:32.820893 (gui/502 [100003]) <Notice>: service inactive: application.com.apple.MobileSMS.1152921500311915211.1152921500311915220
2022-02-24 15:19:32.820899 (gui/502/application.com.apple.MobileSMS.1152921500311915211.1152921500311915220 [5283]) <Notice>: service state: not running
2022-02-24 15:19:32.824518 (gui/502/application.com.apple.MobileSMS.1152921500311915211.1152921500311915220) <Notice>: removing job: caller = runningboardd
2022-02-24 15:19:32.824592 (gui/502 [100003]) <Notice>: removing service: application.com.apple.MobileSMS.1152921500311915211.1152921500311915220
2022-02-24 15:19:32.824727 (gui/502/application.com.apple.MobileSMS.1152921500311915211.1152921500311915220) <Notice>: internal event: PETRIFIED, code = 0
2022-02-24 15:19:32.824733 (gui/502/application.com.apple.MobileSMS.1152921500311915211.1152921500311915220) <Notice>: job state = removed
2022-02-24 15:19:34.469654 (pid/5283 [Messages]) <Notice>: shutting down
2022-02-24 15:19:34.469669 (pid/5283 [Messages]) <Notice>: removing active service: com.apple.coremedia.videodecoder
2022-02-24 15:19:34.469700 (pid/5283/com.apple.coremedia.videodecoder [5288]) <Notice>: signaled service: Killed: 9
2022-02-24 15:19:34.469705 (pid/5283/com.apple.coremedia.videodecoder [5288]) <Notice>: service state: SIGKILLed
2022-02-24 15:19:34.469710 (pid/5283/com.apple.coremedia.videodecoder [5288]) <Notice>: scheduling cleanup in 3 sec after sending Killed: 9
2022-02-24 15:19:34.469747 (pid/5283 [Messages]) <Notice>: removing active service: com.apple.audio.SandboxHelper
2022-02-24 15:19:34.469770 (pid/5283/com.apple.audio.SandboxHelper [5287]) <Notice>: signaled service: Killed: 9
2022-02-24 15:19:34.469774 (pid/5283/com.apple.audio.SandboxHelper [5287]) <Notice>: service state: SIGKILLed
2022-02-24 15:19:34.469779 (pid/5283/com.apple.audio.SandboxHelper [5287]) <Notice>: scheduling cleanup in 3 sec after sending Killed: 9
2022-02-24 15:19:34.469821 (pid/5283/com.apple.sidecar.DisplayMarkup) <Notice>: internal event: PETRIFIED, code = 0
2022-02-24 15:19:34.469833 (pid/5283/com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) <Notice>: internal event: PETRIFIED, code = 0
2022-02-24 15:19:34.469840 (pid/5283/com.apple.WebKit.WebAuthn) <Notice>: internal event: PETRIFIED, code = 0
2022-02-24 15:19:34.469847 (pid/5283/com.apple.WebKit.WebContent) <Notice>: internal event: PETRIFIED, code = 0
2022-02-24 15:19:34.469856 (pid/5283/com.apple.MTLCompilerService) <Notice>: internal event: PETRIFIED, code = 0
2022-02-24 15:19:34.469863 (pid/5283/com.apple.audio.AUHostingService.x86-64) <Notice>: internal event: PETRIFIED, code = 0
2022-02-24 15:19:34.469891 (pid/5283/com.apple.WebKit.GPU) <Notice>: internal event: PETRIFIED, code = 0
2022-02-24 15:19:34.469898 (pid/5283/com.apple.audio.AUHostingService.arm64e) <Notice>: internal event: PETRIFIED, code = 0
2022-02-24 15:19:34.469905 (pid/5283/com.apple.WebKit.Networking) <Notice>: internal event: PETRIFIED, code = 0
2022-02-24 15:19:34.469912 (pid/5283/com.apple.audio.Core-Audio-Driver-Service.helper) <Notice>: internal event: PETRIFIED, code = 0
2022-02-24 15:19:34.469919 (pid/5283/com.apple.WebKit.WebContent.Development) <Notice>: internal event: PETRIFIED, code = 0
2022-02-24 15:19:34.469942 (pid/5283/com.apple.WebKit.Plugin.64) <Notice>: internal event: PETRIFIED, code = 0
2022-02-24 15:19:34.469954 (pid/5283/com.apple.audio.Core-Audio-Driver-Service) <Notice>: internal event: PETRIFIED, code = 0
2022-02-24 15:19:34.471275 (pid/5283/com.apple.audio.SandboxHelper [5287]) <Notice>: service exited: dirty = 0, supported pressured-exit = 1
2022-02-24 15:19:34.471282 (pid/5283/com.apple.audio.SandboxHelper [5287]) <Notice>: exited due to SIGKILL | sent by launchd[1]
2022-02-24 15:19:34.471287 (pid/5283/com.apple.audio.SandboxHelper [5287]) <Notice>: service state: exited
2022-02-24 15:19:34.471292 (pid/5283/com.apple.audio.SandboxHelper [5287]) <Notice>: internal event: EXITED, code = 0
2022-02-24 15:19:34.471297 (pid/5283 [Messages]) <Notice>: service inactive: com.apple.audio.SandboxHelper
2022-02-24 15:19:34.471322 (pid/5283/com.apple.audio.SandboxHelper [5287]) <Notice>: internal event: PETRIFIED, code = 0
2022-02-24 15:19:34.471327 (pid/5283/com.apple.audio.SandboxHelper [5287]) <Notice>: service state: not running
2022-02-24 15:19:34.471377 (pid/5287 [com.apple.audio]) <Notice>: shutting down
2022-02-24 15:19:34.471476 (pid/5287/com.apple.MTLCompilerService) <Notice>: internal event: PETRIFIED, code = 0
2022-02-24 15:19:34.471487 (pid/5287/com.apple.audio.AUHostingService.x86-64) <Notice>: internal event: PETRIFIED, code = 0
2022-02-24 15:19:34.471498 (pid/5287/com.apple.audio.AUHostingService.arm64e) <Notice>: internal event: PETRIFIED, code = 0
2022-02-24 15:19:34.471506 (pid/5287/com.apple.audio.Core-Audio-Driver-Service.helper) <Notice>: internal event: PETRIFIED, code = 0
2022-02-24 15:19:34.471561 (pid/5287/com.apple.audio.Core-Audio-Driver-Service) <Notice>: internal event: PETRIFIED, code = 0
2022-02-24 15:19:34.471591 (pid/5287 [com.apple.audio]) <Notice>: cleaning up
2022-02-24 15:19:34.471603 (system) <Notice>: removing child: pid/5287
2022-02-24 15:19:34.475975 <Notice>: Flushed 35 logs [limit: 20]
2022-02-24 15:19:34.473741 (pid/5283/com.apple.coremedia.videodecoder [5288]) <Notice>: service exited: dirty = 0, supported pressured-exit = 1
2022-02-24 15:19:34.473749 (pid/5283/com.apple.coremedia.videodecoder [5288]) <Notice>: exited due to SIGKILL | sent by launchd[1]
2022-02-24 15:19:34.473754 (pid/5283/com.apple.coremedia.videodecoder [5288]) <Notice>: service state: exited
2022-02-24 15:19:34.473759 (pid/5283/com.apple.coremedia.videodecoder [5288]) <Notice>: internal event: EXITED, code = 0
2022-02-24 15:19:34.473764 (pid/5283 [Messages]) <Notice>: service inactive: com.apple.coremedia.videodecoder
2022-02-24 15:19:34.473786 (pid/5283/com.apple.coremedia.videodecoder [5288]) <Notice>: internal event: PETRIFIED, code = 0
2022-02-24 15:19:34.473855 (pid/5283 [Messages]) <Notice>: cleaning up
2022-02-24 15:19:34.473864 (pid/5283/com.apple.coremedia.videodecoder [5288]) <Notice>: service state: not running
2022-02-24 15:19:34.473890 (pid/5288 [VTDecoderXPCSer]) <Notice>: shutting down
2022-02-24 15:19:34.473900 (pid/5288/com.apple.MTLCompilerService) <Notice>: internal event: PETRIFIED, code = 0
2022-02-24 15:19:34.473908 (pid/5288/com.apple.audio.AUHostingService.x86-64) <Notice>: internal event: PETRIFIED, code = 0
2022-02-24 15:19:34.473915 (pid/5288/com.apple.audio.AUHostingService.arm64e) <Notice>: internal event: PETRIFIED, code = 0
2022-02-24 15:19:34.473921 (pid/5288/com.apple.audio.Core-Audio-Driver-Service.helper) <Notice>: internal event: PETRIFIED, code = 0
2022-02-24 15:19:34.473928 (pid/5288/com.apple.audio.Core-Audio-Driver-Service) <Notice>: internal event: PETRIFIED, code = 0
2022-02-24 15:19:34.473949 (pid/5288 [VTDecoderXPCSer]) <Notice>: cleaning up
2022-02-24 15:19:34.473957 (system) <Notice>: removing child: pid/5283
2022-02-24 15:19:34.473970 (system) <Notice>: removing child: pid/5288
2022-02-24 15:19:34.491242 (gui/502/application.com.apple.ProblemReporter.1152921500312186638.1152921500312186643) <Notice>: internal event: WILL_SPAWN, code = 0
2022-02-24 15:19:34.491259 (gui/502/application.com.apple.ProblemReporter.1152921500312186638.1152921500312186643) <Notice>: service state: spawn scheduled
2022-02-24 15:19:34.491261 (gui/502/application.com.apple.ProblemReporter.1152921500312186638.1152921500312186643) <Notice>: service state: spawning
2022-02-24 15:19:34.491282 <Notice>: Coalition Cache Hit: app<application.com.apple.ProblemReporter.1152921500312186638.1152921500312186643(502)> [3984]
2022-02-24 15:19:34.491363 (gui/502/application.com.apple.ProblemReporter.1152921500312186638.1152921500312186643) <Notice>: launching: non-ipc demand
2022-02-24 15:19:34.495833 (gui/502/application.com.apple.ProblemReporter.1152921500312186638.1152921500312186643 [5289]) <Notice>: xpcproxy spawned with pid 5289
2022-02-24 15:19:34.495869 (gui/502/application.com.apple.ProblemReporter.1152921500312186638.1152921500312186643 [5289]) <Notice>: internal event: SPAWNED, code = 0
2022-02-24 15:19:34.495875 (gui/502/application.com.apple.ProblemReporter.1152921500312186638.1152921500312186643 [5289]) <Notice>: service state: xpcproxy
2022-02-24 15:19:34.495949 (gui/502/application.com.apple.ProblemReporter.1152921500312186638.1152921500312186643 [5289]) <Notice>: internal event: SOURCE_ATTACH, code = 0
2022-02-24 15:19:34.504803 (gui/502/application.com.apple.ProblemReporter.1152921500312186638.1152921500312186643 [5289]) <Notice>: service state: running
2022-02-24 15:19:34.504850 (gui/502/application.com.apple.ProblemReporter.1152921500312186638.1152921500312186643 [5289]) <Notice>: internal event: INIT, code = 0
2022-02-24 15:19:34.504856 (gui/502/application.com.apple.ProblemReporter.1152921500312186638.1152921500312186643 [5289]) <Notice>: job state = running
2022-02-24 15:19:34.504889 (gui/502/application.com.apple.ProblemReporter.1152921500312186638.1152921500312186643 [5289]) <Notice>: Successfully spawned Problem Reporter[5289] because non-ipc demand
2022-02-24 15:19:34.702933 (pid/5289 [Problem Reporte]) <Notice>: uncorking exec source upfront
2022-02-24 15:19:34.702960 (pid/5289 [Problem Reporte]) <Notice>: created
2022-02-24 15:19:34.703643 (pid/5289 [Problem Reporte]) <Notice>: uncorking domain
2022-02-24 15:19:34.705900 (pid/5289 [Problem Reporte]) <Notice>: Service stub created for com.apple.StreamingUnzipService
2022-02-24 15:19:34.706054 (pid/5289 [Problem Reporte]) <Notice>: Service stub created for com.apple.quicklook.QuickLookUIService
2022-02-24 15:19:34.706080 (pid/5289 [Problem Reporte]) <Notice>: Service stub created for com.apple.ImageKit.RecentPictureService
2022-02-24 15:19:34.706322 (pid/5289 [Problem Reporte]) <Notice>: Service stub created for com.apple.AnnotationKit.MigratorService
2022-02-24 15:19:34.706410 (pid/5289/com.apple.sidecar.DisplayMarkup) <Notice>: created the implicit endpoint upfront
2022-02-24 15:19:34.706421 (pid/5289/com.apple.sidecar.DisplayMarkup) <Notice>: draining messages from com.apple.sidecar.DisplayMarkup
2022-02-24 15:19:34.706582 (pid/5289/com.apple.WebKit.GPU) <Notice>: created the implicit endpoint upfront
2022-02-24 15:19:34.706590 (pid/5289/com.apple.WebKit.GPU) <Notice>: draining messages from com.apple.WebKit.GPU
2022-02-24 15:19:34.706644 (pid/5289/com.apple.WebKit.Networking) <Notice>: created the implicit endpoint upfront
2022-02-24 15:19:34.706651 (pid/5289/com.apple.WebKit.Networking) <Notice>: draining messages from com.apple.WebKit.Networking
2022-02-24 15:19:34.706705 (pid/5289/com.apple.WebKit.Plugin.64) <Notice>: created the implicit endpoint upfront
2022-02-24 15:19:34.706711 (pid/5289/com.apple.WebKit.Plugin.64) <Notice>: draining messages from com.apple.WebKit.Plugin.64
2022-02-24 15:19:34.706760 (pid/5289/com.apple.WebKit.WebAuthn) <Notice>: created the implicit endpoint upfront
2022-02-24 15:19:34.706766 (pid/5289/com.apple.WebKit.WebAuthn) <Notice>: draining messages from com.apple.WebKit.WebAuthn
2022-02-24 15:19:34.706806 (pid/5289/com.apple.WebKit.WebContent.Development) <Notice>: created the implicit endpoint upfront
2022-02-24 15:19:34.706814 (pid/5289/com.apple.WebKit.WebContent.Development) <Notice>: draining messages from com.apple.WebKit.WebContent.Development
2022-02-24 15:19:34.706861 (pid/5289/com.apple.WebKit.WebContent) <Notice>: created the implicit endpoint upfront
2022-02-24 15:19:34.706867 (pid/5289/com.apple.WebKit.WebContent) <Notice>: draining messages from com.apple.WebKit.WebContent
2022-02-24 15:19:34.706898 (pid/5289 [Problem Reporte]) <Notice>: Service stub created for com.apple.LookupViewService
2022-02-24 15:19:34.707030 (pid/5289 [Problem Reporte]) <Notice>: Service stub created for com.apple.CoreMLModelSecurityService
2022-02-24 15:19:34.707076 (pid/5289 [Problem Reporte]) <Notice>: Service stub created for com.apple.SafariServices.ExtensionHelper
2022-02-24 15:19:34.707085 (pid/5289 [Problem Reporte]) <Notice>: Service stub created for com.apple.SafariServices
2022-02-24 15:19:34.707368 (pid/5289 [Problem Reporte]) <Notice>: Service stub created for com.apple.ANECompilerService
2022-02-24 15:19:34.707394 (pid/5289 [Problem Reporte]) <Notice>: Service stub created for com.apple.private.ANEStorageMaintainer
2022-02-24 15:19:34.707503 (pid/5289 [Problem Reporte]) <Notice>: Service stub created for com.apple.FileProvider.ArchiveService
2022-02-24 15:19:34.707530 (pid/5289 [Problem Reporte]) <Notice>: Service stub created for com.apple.DataDetectorsActionService
2022-02-24 15:19:34.707541 (pid/5289 [Problem Reporte]) <Notice>: Service stub created for com.apple.DataDetectorsViewService
2022-02-24 15:19:34.707677 (pid/5289/com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) <Notice>: created the implicit endpoint upfront
2022-02-24 15:19:34.707685 (pid/5289/com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) <Notice>: draining messages from com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent
2022-02-24 15:19:34.707818 (pid/5289 [Problem Reporte]) <Notice>: Service stub created for com.apple.intents.intents-helper
2022-02-24 15:19:34.708231 (pid/5289/com.apple.quicklook.externalSatellite.arm64) <Notice>: created the implicit endpoint upfront
2022-02-24 15:19:34.708249 (pid/5289/com.apple.quicklook.externalSatellite.arm64) <Notice>: draining messages from com.apple.quicklook.externalSatellite.arm64
2022-02-24 15:19:34.708299 (pid/5289/com.apple.quicklook.externalSatellite.x86_64) <Notice>: created the implicit endpoint upfront
2022-02-24 15:19:34.708306 (pid/5289/com.apple.quicklook.externalSatellite.x86_64) <Notice>: draining messages from com.apple.quicklook.externalSatellite.x86_64
2022-02-24 15:19:34.708354 (pid/5289/com.apple.quicklook.satellite) <Notice>: created the implicit endpoint upfront
2022-02-24 15:19:34.708361 (pid/5289/com.apple.quicklook.satellite) <Notice>: draining messages from com.apple.quicklook.satellite
2022-02-24 15:19:34.708779 (pid/5289 [Problem Reporte]) <Notice>: Service stub created for com.apple.AppStoreDaemon.StoreAEService
2022-02-24 15:19:34.708809 (pid/5289 [Problem Reporte]) <Notice>: Service stub created for com.apple.AppStoreDaemon.StoreUIService
2022-02-24 15:19:34.708817 (pid/5289 [Problem Reporte]) <Notice>: Service stub created for com.apple.CGXPCServicesAgent
2022-02-24 15:19:34.708824 (pid/5289 [Problem Reporte]) <Notice>: Service stub created for com.apple.CMValidateMovieDataReferenceService
2022-02-24 15:19:34.708837 (pid/5289 [Problem Reporte]) <Notice>: Service stub created for com.apple.ColorSyncXPCAgent
2022-02-24 15:19:34.708845 (pid/5289 [Problem Reporte]) <Notice>: Service stub created for com.apple.CoreDisplay.XPCService
2022-02-24 15:19:34.708856 (pid/5289 [Problem Reporte]) <Notice>: Service stub created for com.apple.ImageIOXPCService
2022-02-24 15:19:34.708862 (pid/5289 [Problem Reporte]) <Notice>: Service stub created for com.apple.LoginUserService
2022-02-24 15:19:34.708919 (pid/5289/com.apple.MTLCompilerService) <Notice>: created the implicit endpoint upfront
2022-02-24 15:19:34.708928 (pid/5289/com.apple.MTLCompilerService) <Notice>: draining messages from com.apple.MTLCompilerService
2022-02-24 15:19:34.708946 (pid/5289 [Problem Reporte]) <Notice>: Service stub created for com.apple.PerfPowerTelemetryClientRegistrationService
2022-02-24 15:19:34.708966 (pid/5289 [Problem Reporte]) <Notice>: Service stub created for com.apple.appkit.xpc.ColorPickerImageLoader
2022-02-24 15:19:34.708978 (pid/5289 [Problem Reporte]) <Notice>: Service stub created for com.apple.appkit.xpc.LegacyExternalColorPickerService.arm64
2022-02-24 15:19:34.708990 (pid/5289 [Problem Reporte]) <Notice>: Service stub created for com.apple.appkit.xpc.LegacyExternalColorPickerService.x86_64
2022-02-24 15:19:34.708998 (pid/5289 [Problem Reporte]) <Notice>: Service stub created for com.apple.appkit.xpc.VersionsUIHelper
2022-02-24 15:19:34.709005 (pid/5289 [Problem Reporte]) <Notice>: Service stub created for com.apple.appkit.xpc.WindowSharingControlViewService
2022-02-24 15:19:34.709013 (pid/5289 [Problem Reporte]) <Notice>: Service stub created for com.apple.appkit.xpc.documentPopoverViewService
2022-02-24 15:19:34.709021 (pid/5289 [Problem Reporte]) <Notice>: Service stub created for com.apple.appkit.xpc.openAndSavePanelService
2022-02-24 15:19:34.709028 (pid/5289 [Problem Reporte]) <Notice>: Service stub created for com.apple.appkit.xpc.sandboxedServiceRunner
2022-02-24 15:19:34.709073 (pid/5289/com.apple.audio.AUHostingService.arm64e) <Notice>: created the implicit endpoint upfront
2022-02-24 15:19:34.709080 (pid/5289/com.apple.audio.AUHostingService.arm64e) <Notice>: draining messages from com.apple.audio.AUHostingService.arm64e
2022-02-24 15:19:34.709125 (pid/5289/com.apple.audio.AUHostingService.x86-64) <Notice>: created the implicit endpoint upfront
2022-02-24 15:19:34.709130 (pid/5289/com.apple.audio.AUHostingService.x86-64) <Notice>: draining messages from com.apple.audio.AUHostingService.x86-64
2022-02-24 15:19:34.709138 (pid/5289 [Problem Reporte]) <Notice>: Service stub created for com.apple.audio.CarbonComponentScanner.x86-64
2022-02-24 15:19:34.709145 (pid/5289 [Problem Reporte]) <Notice>: Service stub created for com.apple.audio.ComponentTagHelper
2022-02-24 15:19:34.709184 (pid/5289/com.apple.audio.Core-Audio-Driver-Service) <Notice>: created the implicit endpoint upfront
2022-02-24 15:19:34.709191 (pid/5289/com.apple.audio.Core-Audio-Driver-Service) <Notice>: draining messages from com.apple.audio.Core-Audio-Driver-Service
2022-02-24 15:19:34.709235 (pid/5289/com.apple.audio.Core-Audio-Driver-Service.helper) <Notice>: created the implicit endpoint upfront
2022-02-24 15:19:34.709241 (pid/5289/com.apple.audio.Core-Audio-Driver-Service.helper) <Notice>: draining messages from com.apple.audio.Core-Audio-Driver-Service.helper
2022-02-24 15:19:34.709250 (pid/5289 [Problem Reporte]) <Notice>: Service stub created for com.apple.audio.DriverHelper
2022-02-24 15:19:34.709256 (pid/5289 [Problem Reporte]) <Notice>: Service stub created for com.apple.audio.InfoHelper
2022-02-24 15:19:34.709263 (pid/5289 [Problem Reporte]) <Notice>: Service stub created for com.apple.audio.SandboxHelper
2022-02-24 15:19:34.709279 (pid/5289 [Problem Reporte]) <Notice>: Service stub created for com.apple.automator.xpc.workflowServiceRunner
2022-02-24 15:19:34.709740 <Notice>: Flushed 25 logs [limit: 20]
2022-02-24 15:19:34.709291 (pid/5289 [Problem Reporte]) <Notice>: Service stub created for com.apple.coremedia.pluginformatreader
2022-02-24 15:19:34.709298 (pid/5289 [Problem Reporte]) <Notice>: Service stub created for com.apple.coremedia.pluginformatreader.zonto
2022-02-24 15:19:34.709306 (pid/5289 [Problem Reporte]) <Notice>: Service stub created for com.apple.coremedia.videodecoder
2022-02-24 15:19:34.709313 (pid/5289 [Problem Reporte]) <Notice>: Service stub created for com.apple.coremedia.videodecoder.zonto
2022-02-24 15:19:34.709321 (pid/5289 [Problem Reporte]) <Notice>: Service stub created for com.apple.coremedia.videoencoder
2022-02-24 15:19:34.709328 (pid/5289 [Problem Reporte]) <Notice>: Service stub created for com.apple.coremedia.videoencoder.zonto
2022-02-24 15:19:34.709336 (pid/5289 [Problem Reporte]) <Notice>: Service stub created for com.apple.extensionkitservice
2022-02-24 15:19:34.709343 (pid/5289 [Problem Reporte]) <Notice>: Service stub created for com.apple.foundation.UserScriptService
2022-02-24 15:19:34.709355 (pid/5289 [Problem Reporte]) <Notice>: Service stub created for com.apple.internal.DataDetectorsRemoteScanner
2022-02-24 15:19:34.709380 (pid/5289 [Problem Reporte]) <Notice>: Service stub created for com.apple.security.pboxd
2022-02-24 15:19:34.709389 (pid/5289 [Problem Reporte]) <Notice>: Service stub created for com.apple.speech.SpeechSynthesisServerXPC
2022-02-24 15:19:34.709401 (pid/5289 [Problem Reporte]) <Notice>: Service stub created for com.apple.textkit.nsattributedstringagent
2022-02-24 15:19:35.121427 (pid/5292 [system_profiler]) <Notice>: uncorking exec source upfront
2022-02-24 15:19:35.121443 (pid/5292 [system_profiler]) <Notice>: created
2022-02-24 15:19:35.121744 (pid/5292 [system_profiler]) <Notice>: uncorking domain
2022-02-24 15:19:35.123527 (pid/5292 [system_profiler]) <Notice>: Service stub created for com.apple.CMValidateMovieDataReferenceService
2022-02-24 15:19:35.123641 (pid/5292 [system_profiler]) <Notice>: Service stub created for com.apple.ColorSyncXPCAgent
2022-02-24 15:19:35.123649 (pid/5292 [system_profiler]) <Notice>: Service stub created for com.apple.CoreDisplay.XPCService
2022-02-24 15:19:35.123661 (pid/5292 [system_profiler]) <Notice>: Service stub created for com.apple.ImageIOXPCService
2022-02-24 15:19:35.123732 (pid/5292/com.apple.MTLCompilerService) <Notice>: created the implicit endpoint upfront
2022-02-24 15:19:35.123742 (pid/5292/com.apple.MTLCompilerService) <Notice>: draining messages from com.apple.MTLCompilerService
2022-02-24 15:19:35.123753 (pid/5292 [system_profiler]) <Notice>: Service stub created for com.apple.PerfPowerTelemetryClientRegistrationService
2022-02-24 15:19:35.123767 (pid/5292 [system_profiler]) <Notice>: Service stub created for com.apple.appkit.xpc.ColorPickerImageLoader
2022-02-24 15:19:35.123777 (pid/5292 [system_profiler]) <Notice>: Service stub created for com.apple.appkit.xpc.LegacyExternalColorPickerService.arm64
2022-02-24 15:19:35.123786 (pid/5292 [system_profiler]) <Notice>: Service stub created for com.apple.appkit.xpc.LegacyExternalColorPickerService.x86_64
2022-02-24 15:19:35.123793 (pid/5292 [system_profiler]) <Notice>: Service stub created for com.apple.appkit.xpc.VersionsUIHelper
2022-02-24 15:19:35.123801 (pid/5292 [system_profiler]) <Notice>: Service stub created for com.apple.appkit.xpc.WindowSharingControlViewService
2022-02-24 15:19:35.123807 (pid/5292 [system_profiler]) <Notice>: Service stub created for com.apple.appkit.xpc.documentPopoverViewService
2022-02-24 15:19:35.123816 (pid/5292 [system_profiler]) <Notice>: Service stub created for com.apple.appkit.xpc.openAndSavePanelService
2022-02-24 15:19:35.123822 (pid/5292 [system_profiler]) <Notice>: Service stub created for com.apple.appkit.xpc.sandboxedServiceRunner
2022-02-24 15:19:35.123873 (pid/5292/com.apple.audio.AUHostingService.arm64e) <Notice>: created the implicit endpoint upfront
2022-02-24 15:19:35.123882 (pid/5292/com.apple.audio.AUHostingService.arm64e) <Notice>: draining messages from com.apple.audio.AUHostingService.arm64e
2022-02-24 15:19:35.123932 (pid/5292/com.apple.audio.AUHostingService.x86-64) <Notice>: created the implicit endpoint upfront
2022-02-24 15:19:35.123938 (pid/5292/com.apple.audio.AUHostingService.x86-64) <Notice>: draining messages from com.apple.audio.AUHostingService.x86-64
2022-02-24 15:19:35.123947 (pid/5292 [system_profiler]) <Notice>: Service stub created for com.apple.audio.CarbonComponentScanner.x86-64
2022-02-24 15:19:35.123953 (pid/5292 [system_profiler]) <Notice>: Service stub created for com.apple.audio.ComponentTagHelper
2022-02-24 15:19:35.124000 (pid/5292/com.apple.audio.Core-Audio-Driver-Service) <Notice>: created the implicit endpoint upfront
2022-02-24 15:19:35.124008 (pid/5292/com.apple.audio.Core-Audio-Driver-Service) <Notice>: draining messages from com.apple.audio.Core-Audio-Driver-Service
```

Comment: what formats have you tried? I'd guess that something is trying to thumbnail the video, and its crashing while trying to read the file.

Comment: Can you edit your Question to include the crash log? (You can use the Console utility to help you find where they are, if you haven't dealt with them before.) The crash log will contain information that could help us determine what's going on. Is this friend's bubbles green, or blue? If green, it could be that something's going wrong converting the video into a video format MMS supports (3GPP?).

Comment: Can you edit the question to provide actual details on the video itself? Size and format? Is the recipient on a Mac themselves or another system?

Comment: @Spiff what command do I use? and this friend's bubble is blue.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I tried to add the video, but I guess it didn't work. ill try again
Edit: I dont have enough reputation to embed it so theres a link instead.

Comment: @ashbit_ Well, you do not have to add the actual video but provide actual details on the video: What format is it in? What is the file size? The GIF is useful to a pointy, but you still are missing core details here like size and format.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I lost the video that I was originally sending in the gif, so I will make a new one: type: .mov; size: 1,257,432 bytes (2.1MB). Still crashes iMessage.

Comment: @Spiff lol I was being dumb. I have included half of the crash report in the post. (half because it was like 60000 characters and the limit is 30000. I hope what I have is still useful)